Как отобразить картинку в кнопке Avalonia C#
Внутри кнопки необходимо отобразить картинку, и иметь возможность изменять эту картинку при нажатии кнопки. Используется Avalonia C#.

<Button><Image Source = "{Binding ...}"/></Button>
